# Unexpected token "(" - Java -- SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, niagara-ax

I am using the Niagara 4 Framework (Java) where I want to send queries to my SQL Server database.

Here is my query : (it does work in SQL Server)

```
SELECT * FROM [RESTART] 
WHERE TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP <DATEADD(minute, 10, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

And I get the following error :

```
 Syntax error near:"DATEADD(" Unexpected token "(" at line 0, column 11.
```

Any idea why do I get this ?

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are both reserved words in SQL Server.

Try changing `TIMSTAMP` to `MY_TIMESTAMP`

Also, contrary to what the name suggests, `TIMESTAMP` is not actually a time, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is...

> [The `TIMESTAMP` data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

and

> [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql)

So comparing a `TIMESTAMP` (not a time) to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (yes a time) is likely causing problems.

Comment: Unfortunately it keep saying me that the error comes from the "(", is there any thing to escape it, any character trick ?I already tried many..

Answer (score 0):

your code with the table name and field name switch to a table I have executes with out error in SSMS,

```
SELECT * FROM [OutgoingAudit] 
WHERE CreateTS > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CreateTS < DATEADD(minute, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

that being said the first part of your where

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

unless TIMESTAMP is a future it will never happen, but that may be what you are looking for